# Django modelformset_factory saves nothing

Tags: django, django-forms

(I'm quite new at django, i googled for this a lot but could not find an answer, so i hope you don't mind the low level question)
There are these Classes:

```
class Cl(models.Model):
    user   = models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Member(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email  = models.EmailField()
    cl     = models.ForeignKey(Cl)

class ClForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cl
```

I want to make a page where i can create an Object of Cl and some related Member Objects (I plan to use django-dynamic-formset but that is not the point here). My view looks like this:

```
class NewView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request):
        cform = ClForm(prefix="cl", instance=Cl(user=request.user))
        MemberFormSet = modelformset_factory(Member)
        memberfs = MemberFormSet(queryset=Member.objects.none())
        return render_to_response(self.template_name, {'cl_form': cform, 'memberformset': memberfs}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    def post(self,request):
        cform = ClForm(request.POST, prefix="cl", instance=Cl(user=request.user))
        MemberFormSet = modelformset_factory(Member)
        memberfs = MemberFormSet(request.POST)
        if cform.is_valid() and memberfs.is_valid():
            new_cl = cform.save()
            new_members = memberfs.save(commit=False)
            for mf in new_members:
                mf.cl = new_cl
                mf.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("unimportant")
        return render_to_response(self.template_name, {'cl_form': cform, 'memberformset': memberfs}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My template looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ memberformset.management_form }}
    <table>
        {{ cl_form }}
        <tr><th colspan="2">Members</th></tr>
        {% with memberformset.empty_form as form %}
            <div id="id_empty_form" style="display:none;">
                {{ form }}
            </div>
        {% endwith %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

My problem is now, that the member is not stored. Also, the memberfs.is_valid() doens't complain, if e.g. the Email field is not filled out correctly.
I also tried the inlineformset_factory, but that didn't worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using the "[empty_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#empty-form)" in that template. The correct way of using the formset is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates). In your example, you should write:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ memberformset.management_form }}
<table>
{{ cl_form }}
<tr><th colspan="2">Members</th></tr>

<!-- THIS IS NOT NECESSARY UNLESS YOU WANT TO ADD FORMS WITH JAVASCRIPT-->    
<div id="id_empty_form" style="display:none;">
{{ memberformset.empty_form }}
</div>
<!-- END NOT NECESSARY-->

{% for form in memberformset.forms %}
    {{ form }}
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```